# Does Upgrading to Windows 10 affect my Virtual Box installation?

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, windows-10, virtual-machine

I am running an XP virtual machine  in Virtual Box 4.3.12 on a 8.1 Windows 64 bit host.

If I upgrade to Windows10, will my virtual machine survive?

I know there are similar thread on similar subjects, but can't find the answer to this specific question.

Any help would be appreciated.
Kenn

Answer (score 0):

I am running about a dozen machines under Virtual Box (although 5.08), and all of them worked fine after the 8.1 -> Windows 10 upgrade. Zero-touch, fully functional.